# Angular 7 Material Expansion Panel flicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

i upgraded to Angular 7.1.0 with:

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^7.1.0"
```

I am using Angular Material Expansion Panels, which are initially expanded false through [expanded]="false".

The Body of the Expansion Panel is visible for some Milliseconds. It looks like a short jump from being expanded to not being expanded.
Does anyone have the same issue?

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <mat-panel-title>
    <div class="NumberAccordionContentWrapper__centered">
      <h2 [class.NumberAccordion__notExpanded]="!isExpanded">{{ headline }}</h2>
    </div>
  </mat-panel-title>

</mat-expansion-panel-header>

<div class="NumberAccordionContentWrapper__centered">

  <ng-template tbHost></ng-template>

</div>
```

Comment: Add relevant code snippets to your question.

Comment: see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13870#issuecomment-502071712

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a bug. and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13870) for it.

It is caused when the expansion panel is **contained and animated**.

[Click to see reproduce demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxfjwi?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

The best workaround so far posted on this thread:

[Click to see the workaround](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue13870-workaround)

Answer (score 3):

This guy posted a temporary work around with css, that seems to work:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11765#issuecomment-447991348

```
::ng-deep .ng-animating div mat-accordion mat-expansion-panel mat-expansion-panel-header {
    height: 48px;
  }
::ng-deep .ng-animating div mat-accordion mat-expansion-panel div.mat-expansion-panel-content {
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I left away the ::ng-deep and added it to my global styles.

Comment: a nice solution: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13870#issuecomment-502071712